# Convert string to date class, format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: r, date

I need a way to compare a vector of dates formatted as such `dd/mm/yyyy` and with a single date, currently a string that looks like this `yyyymmdd`

when comparing each vector element I need R to create a variable assigning 100 if the statement is `TRUE` and 200 if it is `FALSE`

In order to do this I created a function

`tmp_ID` and `tmp_MD` are my dates vectors

`tgt_date` is the single date that I need to compare

FUNCTION:

```
select_alive<-function(x){

  tmp_ID <- as.Date(x$Issue.date,sep="","%d/%m/%Y")

  tmp_MD <- as.Date(x$Maturity.date,"%d/%m/%Y")  

  tgt_date <- format.Date(as.Date(target_dates_54,"%Y%m%d","%d-%m-%Y"), "%d/%m/%Y")

  Security.Status <-ifelse((tgt_date < tmp_MD) & (tgt_date >= tmp_ID), 100,200)

  x<-cbind(x,Security.Status)

  return(x)
}
```

The function should create a flag that assigns 100 if `tgt_date` falls between `tmp_ID` and `tmp_MD` else assign 200 but the flags don't get assigned correctly.

`Issue.date` and `Maturity.date` belong to a data frame and look as follows

```
Issue.date    Maturity.date
06/11/2003    07/11/2033
01/04/2011    NA
03/02/2011    23/03/2012
02/01/2006    02/01/2011
19/11/2010    25/03/2011
```

`target_dates_54` is a vector of strings containing dates

```
target_dates_54 <- c("20110131","20110228","20110331","20110430".....)
```

For the sake of simplicity lets assume that it only contains one string say `"20110430"`

So in this case `tgt_date` and `target_dates_54` are the same.

I need R to take this string and create a variable that assigns 100 to rows where `"20110430"` falls between the range of `Issue.date` and `Maturity.date`
200 should be assigned otherwise

I have identified two possible issues:

1. ifelse might not be able to compare a single date with each element of the vector
2. class of `tgt_date` needs to be converted to Date and format should be dd/mm/yyyy

I have not found a way to solve either of the issues. Any suggestion is very appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: is `x` a single row of a data frame? or is it multiple rows? is `tgt_date` a single value or a vector?

Comment: x is a data frame and tgt_date is a single value

Comment: Why don't you post some of your data.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I have added more info to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `tgt_date` is a single value (not a vector), try this:

```
library(lubridate)

x <- transform(x, Issue.date = dmy(Issue.date), Maturity.date = dmy(Maturity.date))
tgt_date <- ymd(tgt_date)

x <- mutate(x, Security.Status = ifelse((tgt_date < Maturity.date) & (tgt_date >= Issue.date), 100, 200))
```

Using the data you provided:

```
> x
  Issue.date Maturity.date Security.Status
1 2003-11-06    2033-11-07             100
2 2011-04-01          <NA>              NA
3 2011-02-03    2012-03-23             100
4 2006-01-02    2011-01-02             200
5 2010-11-19    2011-03-25             200
```

Note: I'm using the `lubridate` package to convert the dates.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs some change for a single `target_date`

```
 select_alive<-function(x, target_date){
 tmp_ID <- as.Date(x$Issue.date,sep="","%d/%m/%Y")
 tmp_MD <- as.Date(x$Maturity.date,"%d/%m/%Y")  
 tgt_date <- as.Date(target_date,"%Y%m%d") ######
 Security.Status <-ifelse((tgt_date < tmp_MD) & (tgt_date >= tmp_ID), 100,200)
 x<-cbind(x,Security.Status)
 return(x)
 }

target_date <- "20110430"

 select_alive(x, target_date)
 #Issue.date Maturity.date Security.Status
 #1 06/11/2003    07/11/2033             100
 #2 01/04/2011          <NA>              NA
 #3 03/02/2011    23/03/2012             100
 #4 02/01/2006    02/01/2011             200
 #5 19/11/2010    25/03/2011             200
```

For multiple dates, I am not clear about the condition.  Perhaps, `?cut` could be used.